# Caan someone check my wiring of a digital timer?

Tags: timer

I bought a "Woods model 590818/59028" digital timer from Coleman.com through Amazon for my front porch. After wiring, the On/Off button stays lit and does nothing else. I'm hoping someone can check my wiring to rule out a defective timer.

In the wall fixture, there are two lines. The one with the hot wire (at the BOTTOM) has three wires: black (120 VAC hot), ground, and white.

The line (at the TOP) has four wires: black, red, ground and white.

The timer has four wires: black (hot), red (load), ground and white.

I connected the black (hot 120 VAC) wire to the black (hot) wire on the timer.

I tapped the white wire on the timer into the white wires that are connected as well as the ground wire.

I believe I have everything correct so far. Now for the tricky part.

I connected the red wire from the timer to the black wire from the TOP line, since it was connected to the old timer I replaced. The On/Off button stays lit. The front porch light cannot be lit. I pressed "reset" as instructed in the accompanying directions.

So I connected the red wire from the timer to the red wire from the top line. Same result.

Is my original wiring correct and the timer defective, or have I got the wiring all wrong?

Comment: Can you add photos of the wiring coming into wall fixture? Was the wall fixture controlled from more than one switch before you started making changes?

Comment: The presence of the extra red wire in the switch box means that this is not a simple installation.  You will need to provide more information, ideally information on how the previous switch was connected and whether there are any other switches that control this light.  You might also open up the porch light and see if the red wire is present there.. if it isn't that implies there is another junction somewhere, possibly hidden.

Answer (score 1):

[Instruction Manual](http://www.ccixpress.com/cci/Marketing/Woods_US_Timer_Instructions/TM_59018_InstrMan.pdf).

The issue may be more with how the old timer was connected.  How were the Black and Red at top connected for the old timer?

Does your light have two separate switches?  If yes, you could have a three way switch.